# Using boost for semi-infinite integral

Tags: c++, boost, integration

I am trying to perform two semi-infinite integrals

[image]

[image]

I am interested in using Boost to perform this integral. However, I am not seeing anything, [odeint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/index.html) does not seem to be able to handle semi-infinite domains.

Comment: odeint solves the initial value problem (IVP) of ordinary differential equations. This here is a different problem and I am not sure if you can transform it into an IVP.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a really large number (1E+300) in place of the infinity (look up "Improper Integrals").  Or you might be able to use a change of variables, as explained in the *Numerical Recipes* book/website (search for Midinf).